# groovy fibonacchi trampoline and memoize

Tags: groovy

I am trying to evaluate fibonacchi sequence for `10000000`.

Using basic `trampoline` it looks like this

```
def rFibonacchi
rFibonacchi = { 
    BigInteger n, prev = 0, next = 1 ->
        (n < 2) ? prev : rFibonacchi.trampoline(n - 1, prev, next + prev)
}.trampoline()
```

But using `trampoline & memoize` combo I am constantly getting `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
def tFibonacchi, mFibonacchi

mFibonacchi = { BigInteger n, prev, next ->
    n < 2 ? prev : tFibonacchi.trampoline(n - 1, next, prev + next)
}.memoize()

tFibonacchi = { BigInteger n, prev = 0, next = 1 ->
    mFibonacchi(n, next, prev)
}.trampoline()

tFibonacchi(10000000); // GC overhead limit exceed
```

Is it my algorithm's issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm doesn't get any bonus from using memoization. To quote [the groovy docs on memoization:](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_memoization)

> Memoization allows the result of the call of a closure to be cached. It is interesting if the computation done by a function (closure) is slow, but you know that this function is going to be called often with the same arguments. A typical example is the Fibonacci suite. A naive implementation may look like this:
>
> ```
> def fib
> fib = { long n -> n<2?n:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) }
> assert fib(15) == 610 // slow!
> ```
>
> It is a naive implementation because 'fib' is often called recursively with the same arguments, leading to an exponential algorithm:
>
> - computing `fib(15)` requires the result of `fib(14)` and `fib(13)`
> - computing `fib(14)` requires the result of fib(13) and `fib(12)`
>
> Since calls are recursive, you can already see that we will compute the same values again and again, although they could be cached. This naive implementation can be "fixed" by caching the result of calls using memoize:
>
> ```
> fib = { long n -> n<2?n:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) }.memoize()
> assert fib(25) == 75025 // fast!
> ```
>
> The cache works using the actual values of the arguments.

You are using an improved Fibonacci algorithm to the above one. Yours is more iterative and it never calls `mFibonacchi` twice with all of the same arguments. This causes groovy to cache the result of each call, but never actually use this cache, which leads to the memory overflow. The memoization is actually an issue.

Your algorithm is equivalent to:

```
BigInteger fibonacchi(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger prev = 0, next = 1
    for (; n > 2; n--) {
        BigInteger temp = prev
        prev = next
        next = prev + temp
    }
    return prev
}
```

Comment: So is it possible to fix it in order to use cached invokations?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to switch to the recursive version of computation
[i.e. F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)] as in the example on the groovy website and my comment above.

Comment: I though that it is possible to combine trampoline and memoize for fibonacchi. For just recursive (though with StackOverflow error) it is too easy.

Comment: trampoline does not allows to `+`

Comment: Woops. You are correct. My mistake. I removed my old comment. I'll do some thinking, but what you have may be the best way to combine then. The main purpose of memoizing the way that you are is to make subsequent call to tFibonacchi fast. You could add an annotation to limit the size of the cache, but that defeats this purpose.

Comment: I think it might be possible by implementing some kind of custom trampoline where I recurse iteratively - not reaching StackOverflow but deep enough